# Can this insert be shortened

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can this insert be shortened?  It seems like might be able to skip the foreach.

```
if (users == null)
{
    users = new List<User>();
    foreach (UserIDGroupID userIDGroupID in UserIDsGroupIDs.Where(x => x.GroupID == ID))
    {
        Users.AddRange(LibraryUsers.Where(x => x.ID == userIDGroupID.UserID));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Users.AddRange(LibraryUsers.Where(x=>x.Groups.Any(g=>g.GroupID==ID)));`  This of course assumes you have a navigation property on LibraryUsers to Groups.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Does not use UserIDsGroupIDs

Comment: That is the point.  If this is something like EF, nHibernate or LINQtoSQL, and your LibraryUser class has a navigation property from it to Group, then you don't need the UserIDsGroupIDs collection at all, and you will generate a single SQL query to get what you want rather than multiple or many multiple.  But you would need to provide your model class, you database structure (if this is even database related), and what is backing your collections.  Only then could I give you a better answer.

Comment: @RobertMcKee but I don't want to make a server call.  I want to use one list to mange User to Groups and Group to Users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `Contains` to a previous selection of the ids. For sample:

```
if (users == null)
{
    var ids = UserIDsGroupIDs.Select(x => x.UserID);

    users = LibraryUsers.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I will test this out.

Comment: I suggest you convert `IEnumerable` to `HashSet`, it will increase a performance of `Contains`, so you will check that the item from `LibraryUsers` exists in `UserIDsGroupIDs` and this checking will cost the O(c)

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria even if is it linq to sql? Linq to objects I agree!

Comment: This doesn't have the filter of group id. Unless I'm missing something you would want to add the ".Where(x => x.GroupID == ID)" in front of the select.